# How can I combine Query#getSQL() and Query#getBindValues() to make a "JOOQless" query?

Tags: java, jooq

The jOOQ documentation explains how to use it as a query builder: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/use-cases/jooq-as-a-sql-builder-without-codegeneration/

I would like to go a bit further: would it be possible to use jOOQ to generate the query without relying on jOOQ further? I will explain.

I will reuse the example that was given by jOOQ docs:

```java
// Fetch a SQL string from a jOOQ Query in order to manually execute it with another tool.
// For simplicity reasons, we're using the API to construct case-insensitive object references, here.
Query query = create.select(field("BOOK.TITLE"), field("AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME"), field("AUTHOR.LAST_NAME"))
                    .from(table("BOOK"))
                    .join(table("AUTHOR"))
                    .on(field("BOOK.AUTHOR_ID").eq(field("AUTHOR.ID")))
                    .where(field("BOOK.PUBLISHED_IN").eq(1948));
String sql = query.getSQL();
List<Object> bindValues = query.getBindValues();
```

In this example, we can take the `sql` and `bindValues` to create a `PreparedStatement`, but if we would like to query for another "BOOK.PUBLISHED_IN" year, we would need to either:

1. Pass the desired year to the jOOQ query builder again.
2. Know ahead of time that, when the query is rendered, the "BOOK.PUBLISHED_IN" parameter is the bind parameter "1", and pass it to a `PreparedStatement` in that order.

I would like to not go with option 1, because I would not use jOOQ as a dependency after my query is generated, and the problem with option 2 is that, without jOOQ, I would need to "assume" and possibly manually review the rendered SQL and adjust the query parameters order.

I tried using `Query#getParams()`, but the return type is a `Map` which is not reliable for "ordering", it also contains the `Param` objects produced by `DSL.inline`, which I do not need because they were already rendered in the query.

I am searching for solutions to know the bind order without relying on jOOQ after the query is generated. Following the example above, we could have a named parameter called `year` and "ask" jOOQ what positions the property has, in this case it would be 1, but if the same named parameter appears multiple times in the query, it could return many positions.

Comment: Why do you want to do all that?

Comment: @LukasEder as I explained in the other comment, I am generating queries to be consumed by other systems. So jooq would not be always present in these systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to map input bind parameters to output bind parameters

You could obviously use [named parameters for this](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/named-parameters/). In fact, that's the only way you can guarantee to have a reliable mapping between your input values and your output parameter positions. One way to do this is to form your query like this:

```java
int i = 0;
Query query = create
    .select(
         field("BOOK.TITLE"), 
         field("AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME"), 
         field("AUTHOR.LAST_NAME"))
    .from(table("BOOK"))
    .join(table("AUTHOR"))
    .on(field("BOOK.AUTHOR_ID").eq(field("AUTHOR.ID")))
    .where(field("BOOK.PUBLISHED_IN").eq(param("p" + (++i), 1984)));
```

There are multiple reasons why you cannot solve this in any other way:

1. Some emulations will have to repeat their arguments. For example, look at how [`RPAD(a, b, c)` is emulated in SQL Server](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/string-functions/rpad-function/): `a + replicate(c, b - len(a))`, so the argument `a` is repeated twice, meaning the mapping `input-bind-position -> output-bind-position` isn't a function as you were assuming.
2. Some emulations require inlining of the bind variable, because of limitations of the underlying SQL dialect. For example, when using [`JSON_TABLE`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/json-table-function/), some dialects support bind variables for their JSON paths, others only support literals, e.g. `'$.a'` (this is still a problem when you're using named parameters!)

### Remark about avoiding code generation and execution with jOOQ

You probably have a valid use case for both avoiding code generation and query execution with jOOQ, just in case someone else reads this answer, here's a useful set of links to:

- [Why you should use jOOQ with code generation](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/)
- [Why you should execute queries with jOOQ](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-execute-jooq-queries-with-jooq/)

Comment: Thanks Lukas for expanding on the rendering behavior, I will try your approach. Jooq is an awesome tool, thank you for creating it.

My use case is that I need to generate queries and mappings to be consumed in other systems, so as much as I like jooq, it would not be always available in these systems.

Expanding on your answer, is there an API that could help with these edge cases while avoiding named parameters? I took a brief look into `RenderContext`, but I am not sure it is the right place to "hack" into to collect the positional parameters.

Comment: @LouizFC: Only *you* (i.e. your application) know what constitutes a bind value of interest, and what doesn't. jOOQ can't decide that for you. So, I don't see how you could delegate this work to jOOQ. In fact, I also don't know how jOOQ could provide you with an alternative model of such a query, but not impose yet another jOOQ dependency on your application.

Comment: Thanks Lukas. I think this pretty much settles it then. I will wait a bit to accept the answer so other people can get a chance to answer it too.